# Facebook Authentication not working

Tags: facebook, authentication

So I set up the php sdk in the header:

```
//set up Facebook object webroot is a variable that is defined above in the page        
require_once (''.$webroot.'facebook-platform/facebook.php');
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'ID',
      'secret' => 'SECRET',
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    if($facebook->getUser() != 0){ // If someone's logged in...
        //Code in here that does stuff
        }
    ?>
```

and then I have this code in the main body for the login button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

But hitting the login button does nothing and `getUser` always returns `0`. This is just meant to be a fb login button on my website, the only info I need is the FB user id since I use that to tie to my MySQL database to access a bunch of info for that user on my website. But it isn't working at all.

Comment: Have you tried manually creating the login link such as  

<a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login</a>

Comment: Did you checked what passed to `auth.login` event? Have you tried to use [example from PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php) with your appId and secret?

Comment: when you pass in your app id, do you create it as a variable and pass that it? Or do you pass it in the quotes. I noticed an issue where, if the app id is not in quotes then it could be interpreted as a float, and hence your login url would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In the Javascript portion of your code, you have to have PHP echo out the ID. It won't understand constants. so 
`FB.init ({appID : '<?php echo ID;?>',....`